# Providing cloned virtual environment to multiple clients

Tags: vpn, vmware-esxi, deployment, network-design

I have a virtual environment created with vmware esxi consisting on a ipfire and a internal network with some vms.

What would be the best way to clone this environment, on demand, so each client could have access to a vpn that leads to copies of the same vms on his own private network? (the client would only have a ovpn, or other, and connect to the vms).

I want it to be scalable, since I don't know if I will have 1000 clients or even more.

I wouldn't mind changing any of the software.

an example of 2 clones could be:
client1 connects to vpn and gains access to 10.10.10.1
client2 connects to vpn and gains access to 10.10.10.1
where the ip is the same but they are in different networks.

or it could be:
client1 connects to vpn and gains access to 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.20
client2 connects to vpn and gains access to 10.10.10.21 to 10.10.10.40

where 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.20 have the same vms as 10.10.10.21 to 10.10.10.40 in same order, but there is no communication between clients, and between vms.

Comment: [You have a clear X and Y Problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem), Please update your question, so it makes sense. I lost the point latest after, I can only work on 255 clients - how much do you need, how many users are you need, which is the IP-Space you use?

Comment: I have updated my question, I would be thankful if you could read again.

Comment: Firstly I think you need a system architect, secondly the only way to get vSphere to do what you want is either with some form of third-party front-end, or using VMware's Cloud Director or VIO - both of which are complex and spendy. Another option might be OpenStack, it has multi-tenant operations build in on day one - but it's not as good a hypervisor as the VMware stack.

Comment: it sound to me like you wanna create a VPN service for public, if i understand the point well enough?

Comment: I want a single vpn connection to machines that I made, and clone that network for each client that I will have.

In a smaller network example, it would be: giving each client access to a ubuntu and windows vms, for personal use, through a vpn.